# How to color a cluster histogram in gluplot?

Tags: colors, statistics, 2d, gnuplot, histogram

This is my gnuoplot script:

```
#
set title "prova"
set auto x
set grid y
set ylabel "% of total"
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill pattern 1 border lt -1
set boxwidth 1.0
set xtic rotate by -0 scale 0  
plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti col, '' u 3 ti col, '' u 4 ti col 
#
```

this is the file data.dat:

```
#
level   V(89.4%) ER     I
Liv1    -6.7    -4.6    -9.8
Liv2    -20.5   -14.6   -25.8
Liv3    40.0    45.1    36.5
Liv4    24.8    28.7    22.2
Liv5    8.1     7.0     5.7
#
```

and this is the result:

[image]

So:

1. I want that the 'liv1' three columns are filled in red, the 'liv2' 3 columns are filled in orange, the 'liv3' 3 columns are filled in white, the 'liv4' 3 columns are filled in light green, and the 'liv5' 3 columns are filled in dark green
2. I want that the 1st column, the 2nd colunmn and the 3th column of each of the five sub-histo has a black texture (pattern) that can be shown in the legend as in my actualy pic

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For the liv3 bars, do you really mean white? With white patterns all 3 bars would look the same. Maybe you meant black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, right away I don't know how you could do it with `style histogram`,
hence, I would do it `with boxes` where you have full flexibility.

The first plot command is used for the boxes with variable color (check `linecolor variable`).
The colors are taken from a string list (check `help word` and `help colorspec`). `$0` is the pseudcolumn 0, i.e. the row number index (check `help pseudocolumns`).
The second plot command is plotting nothing (`NaN`), but it is just for the xticlabels and a grey version of the fill patterns in the legend.

**Script:**

```
### defined colors and fill patterns for a box chart
reset session

$Data <<EOD
level   V(89.4%) ER     I
Liv1    -6.7    -4.6    -9.8
Liv2   -20.5   -14.6   -25.8
Liv3    40.0    45.1    36.5
Liv4    24.8    28.7    22.2
Liv5     8.1     7.0     5.7
EOD

set title "prova"
set grid y
set ylabel "% of total"
set style fill pattern 1 border lt -1
set boxwidth 1.0 absolute
set key noautotitle
set xzeroaxis ls 1 lc "black"
PosX(row,col) = 0

#             red      orange   black    light-green dark-green"
myColors   = "0xff0000 0xffa500 0x000000 0x90ee90    0x006400"
myColor(i) = int(word(myColors,int(i+1)))

stats $Data u 0 nooutput   # get number of columns
N = STATS_columns

plot for [col=2:N] $Data u ($0*N+col):col:(myColor($0)) skip 1 w boxes lc rgb var, \
     for [col=2:N]    '' u ($0*N+N/2.+1):(NaN):xtic(1) w boxes fill pattern col-1 lc "grey" ti columnheader(col)
### end of script
```

**Result:** (patterns you get in wxt terminal)

[image]